# Regarding Classification using Naive Bayes, improving results

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I have a dataset that has 10 classes, 40 examples per class (total 400 examples).
I have extracted about 27 features for each example.  I used a naive bayes classifier and, using ten fold cross validation, got about 96.75% accuracy.

I noticed from the confusion matrix that only two of the ten classes were getting several examples confused while the rest always were all classified correctly.  I decided to then remove all other classes except for those two, keeping the same number of features, and re-ran the naive bayes classifier; it was always able to classify the examples two classes correctly.

I am confused as to why this happened and what to do to improve my overall classifier.  I wasn't really expecting the bayes classifier to be able to predict those two classes any better.  I tried various fold combinations, percentage splits, and it was always classifying the two "problem" classes correctly in the absence of all the other 8 classes.  Am I touching on the idea of boosting/bagging/ensemble methods for classification?  Should my strategy be to deal with the "problem" classes using one classifier and deal with the rest of the classes using another?  I suppose I would have liked to have made one classifier that could just handle everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the **two difficult classes are completely or partially obscured by one of the other classes.**  Removing the other classes may allow you to differentiate between the two, but **it may still be difficult to separate the two classes from the whole of the data.**

You can imagine that case being true below (where the blue dots are obscured by the red).  Removing the red dots make the blue and black dots very easy to separate.

[image]

To see if you would benefit from multiple classifiers (as you suggest) I would combine the two difficult classes into one, and check your classification ability in the presence of the other classes.  If you are able to do this accurately then you could feel confident proceeding with your multiple classifiers.